# React with jest renderIntoDocument always returns null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have been trying to test a react app using jest. but couldn't even move a step further. I have created a Simple Component and tried to test it with jest.

here is the component

```
import React from 'react'

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component{
 render(){
    return(
        <h1>This is a Test Component</h1>
    )
 }
}
```

and the test

```
jest.dontMock('../src/components/TestComponent')

import TestComponent from '../src/components/TestComponent'
var React = require('react'),
TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils')

describe('TestComponent', () =>{

it('should Render Somehow',() => {
    let testComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <TestComponent />
    )
    let com = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(testComponent, 'h1')
      expect(com.length).toEqual(1);
    console.log(com)
})
})
```

the output of testComponent is not really null it prints out something starting with 'Testcomponent{' but when I tried to find out anything from the testComponent using the scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag method this is a null always .

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to change

```
jest.dontMock('../src/components/TestComponent')
```

to

```
jest.unmock('../src/components/TestComponent')
```

[link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/597)